# KeyError: 0 when converting bs4 xml to pandas df

Tags: pandas

I am trying to import xml to pandas using bs4.

The bs4 import works, but getting pandas to recognise the xml is problematic.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/data.xml'
geturl = requests.get(url).text
data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(geturl, 'lxml')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

I am expecting the df to show the first 5 rows of data, but instead i get the following error:

> KeyError: 0

Why is pandas producing this KeyError: 0?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to parse the xml data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five different charts in the xml file. Which one do you want? This is an example using the first chart:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# xml url
xml = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/data.xml'
# GET request and create soup
r = requests.get(xml)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')

# list comprehension to create a list of all the charts in the xml file
charts = [chart for chart in soup.findAll('chart')]

# list comprehension to get the observation index and value of the first chart (i.e, charts[0])
data = [[ob['index'], ob['value']] for ob in charts[0].findAll('observation')]

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Value'])
df.head()

        Date      Value
0   1-Aug-07  870261.00
1   8-Aug-07  865453.00
2  15-Aug-07  864931.00
3  22-Aug-07  862775.00
4  29-Aug-07  872873.00
```

## Update

You can iterate through all the charts and append to a dict. You will then call each DataFrame by the title of the chart:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# xml url
xml = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/data.xml'
# GET request and create soup
r = requests.get(xml)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')

# list comprehension to create a list of all the charts in the xml file
charts = [chart for chart in soup.findAll('chart')]

# empty dict
df_list = {}

for chart in charts:
    # list comprehension to get the observation index and value
    data = [[ob['index'], ob['value']] for ob in chart.findAll('observation')]
    # create DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Value'])
    # create key from the the chart title and append df
    df_list[chart['title']] = []
    df_list[chart['title']].append(df)

# calling the second chart
df_list['Selected Assets of the Federal Reserve'][0].head()


        Date      Value
0   1-Aug-07  870261.00
1   8-Aug-07  865453.00
2  15-Aug-07  864931.00
3  22-Aug-07  862775.00
4  29-Aug-07  872873.00
```

Comment: Hi Chris, this is fantastic! thank you very much for your help!